# allPrimes printing out a empty tuple Python

Tags: python, tuples, primes

So I have this code and it is supposed to print out a tuple with all the prime numbers in it. But instead, it's just printing out a empty tuple...

> Can anyone tell me why?
>   I also MUST USE A TUPLE.

```
def isPrime(number):
 for i in range(2,int(number**(0.5))+1):
     if number % i == 0:
         return False
     else:
         return True


def allPrimes(number):
    tup=()
    for i in range(1,number):
        if isPrime(i) == True:
            tup += (i,)
    print(tup)

allPrimes(26)
```

> Here is the correct code

```
def isPrime(number):
    if number < 2:
       return False
    for i in range(2, int(number ** (0.5)) + 1):
        if number % i == 0:
            return False
    return True



def allPrimes(number):
    tup=()
    for i in range(1,number):
        if isPrime(i) == True:
            tup += (i,)
        print(tup)

allPrimes(26)
out[1]: (2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23)
```

Comment: I just made some edits to my code and it still does not work.

Comment: I have to use a tuple, it is for a assaignment

Comment: It's usually better to use a `list` to build it up. Even if it must be a `tuple` at the end, it's much faster to build the `list` then convert to `tuple` once at the end than to constantly create new `tuple`s one element longer. Just initialize `ret = []`, change `tup += (i,)` to `ret.append(i)`, and when you `return`/`print` it, do `print(tuple(ret))` or `return tuple(ret)` to convert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `isPrime()` function starts at 1. Every integer is evenly divisible by 1, so it always returns `False`. Start at 2 instead.

```
def isPrime(number):
    if number < 2:
       return False
    for i in range(2, int(number ** (0.5)) + 1):
        if number % i == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

Also, your allPrimes should probably use a list rather than a tuple, and you could use just `isPrime(i)` instead of `isPrime(i) == True`, but it'll work the way it is.

Comment: Not quite right yet... this would return True for 1

Comment: I just made thos changes, but it says that 3 is not a prime number

Comment: No it does not.

Comment: Admittedly a minor optimization (only reduce work factor by half), but changing the initial test to `if number <= 2: return number == 2` followed by `if number % 2 == 0: return False` would allow you to change the `for` loop to `for i in range(3, int(number ** 0.5) + 1, 2):`, thereby avoiding testing for divisibility by all the even numbers, halving work.

Comment: @drewteriyaki: If you didn't have the initial `if` test, it would report 0 and 1 (and all negative numbers) as prime (because the loop never runs). They are not.

Answer (score 1):

It's because your isPrime function doesn't work.

`number % 1`, i.e. 'remainder when divided by 1', will always be zero for integers.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues in your code:

1) In `isPrime` returns `True` on the wrong line

2) You are printing `tup` outside the function scope

3) You are not handling case of `1` (in `isPrime`)

4) You are using `tuple` to store primes, `list` is better; it is much more efficient.

5) Use snake case for functions names in Python.

Making the changes:

```
def is_prime(number):
    if number < 2:
        return False

    for i in range(2,int(number**(0.5))+1):
        if number % i == 0:
            return False

    return True

def all_primes(number):
    my_primes = []
    for i in range(1,number):
        if is_prime(i): 
            my_primes.append(i)
    return my_primes

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print all_primes(40)
```

Comment: I'd suggest differentiate between implementation/logical errors and good/Python conventions (points 1-4 and 5), so OP does not get confused that the names matter. But maybe I'm just too picky - in that case sorry ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Because in the first iteration if `number % i != 0:` the number is prime, you have to return `True` at the end of the iteration an break it if `number % i == 0:

```
def isPrime(number):
    res = True
    if number < 2:
        res = False
    else:
        for i in range(2,int(number**0.5)+1):
            if number % i == 0:
                res = False
                break
    return res
```

Comment: Please check this.